# How can I make a JavaScript class wait for a specific key to be pressed before continuing?

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is to wait until the correct key is pressed for it to continue

The code i've done so far is this:

```js
class exampleClass {
    async waitForKeyPress() {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
        
            const listener = (e) => {
                document.body.removeEventListener("keydown", listener);
                if(e.key == "z") {resolve(); alert("e");}
                else {
                    this.waitForKeyPress();
                }
            }
            document.body.addEventListener("keydown", listener);
        });
    }

    async doStuff() {
        await this.waitForKeyPress();
        console.log("correct key pressed");
        //do stuff
    }
}

let exampleObject = new exampleClass();
exampleObject.doStuff();
```

This doesn't work for me since if I press a different key then it doesn't detect that the z key is pressed for some reason
The part that is confusing for me is is that if you do

```js
async function waitForKeyPress() {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
        
            const listener = (e) => {
                document.body.removeEventListener("keydown", listener);
                if(e.key == "z") resolve();
                else {
                    this.waitForKeyPress();
                }
            }
            document.body.addEventListener("keydown", listener);
        });
    }

    async function doStuff() {
        await this.waitForKeyPress();
        console.log("correct key pressed");
        //do stuff
    }

    doStuff();
```

it works, the only difference is that it's not in a class. However, I would like it to be in a class

Comment: Tried your code with class. Work as expected, no issue. What is the problem you encountering?

Comment: If you press a different key, then press "z", it doesn't work. I forgot to put that in the question, I'll edit it, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Same here. Your first code block works as you described it. FYI, I've edited your question to make your code runnable in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove listener only when `z` is pressed instead of removing it prematurely.

```
class exampleClass {
    async waitForKeyPress() {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            const listener = (e) => {
                if(e.key === "z") {
                    window.removeEventListener("keydown", listener);
                    resolve();
                }
            }
            window.addEventListener("keydown", listener);
        });
    }

    async doStuff() {
        await this.waitForKeyPress();
        console.log("correct key pressed");
        //do stuff
    }
}

let exampleObject = new exampleClass();
exampleObject.doStuff();
```

Without promise,

```
class exampleClass {
    constructor() {
        // the reason for this line is because "this"
        // inside doStuff will be window instead of
        // the class itself.
        this.doStuff = this.doStuff.bind(this)
        window.addEventListener("keydown", this.doStuff);
    }
    
    doStuff(e) {
        if(e.key !== 'z') return
        window.removeEventListener("keydown", this.doStuff)
        console.log("correct key pressed");
        //do stuff
    }
}

let exampleObject = new exampleClass();
```

Comment: Cool. Btw you don't necessarily have to use promises. I've added an example.